# Loggers - defining the processing handler (appender) in Wildfly

Tags: java, logging, log4j, wildfly

I have defined different Handlers in the Wildfly Standalone-full.xml. (in real log4j they were called appenders...)

so now, i create a new logger in a java file:

```
Logger log=Logger.getLogger(class.name)
```

How do i define which handler should be used to process it? 
How is the Handler chosen automatically? Based on the package name? Can't be the class name, that class was nowhere defined in the configs. Where is this defined?

Answer (score 0):

In standalone.xml/domain.xml, Create log handler like below

```
           <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="HANDLER_NAME" autoflush="true">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="audit.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

And in the same file you can configure for which package you want to apply that handler alongwith the log level

```
           <logger category="com.package"> //here the package name for which you have created the handler
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="HANDLER_NAME"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
```

Comment: It's better to use CLI, the web console or some form of a management operation to make changes.